# How many monitors can Intel® Pro Graphics 630 support?

Tags: graphics-card, intel-graphics, dell-precision

I have Dell Precision 5520 that goes with

> NVIDIA Quadro M1200 with 4GB GDDR5 dedicated memory
>
> and Intel® Pro Graphics 630

How many displays I can use at the same time?

I understand that since `NVIDIA Quadro M1200` designed to have no connectors then the burden goes to `Intel® Pro Graphics 630`.

I have seen many time answers on multiple forums that `Intel® Pro Graphics 630` can have **up to 3** screens working at the same time. And my experience proves it.

But I have not seen any trustworthy source - like on `intell.com` or `dell.com` that would make such claim.

So my question is:

> How many monitors can handle Intel® Pro Graphics 630? Please provide trustworthy source.

I'm upset with the consultant that have sold me my `Dell Precision 5520` and `Dell Thunderbolt Dock WD19TBS`.

I have to explain them my point with a trustworthy source, that I cannot just update drivers or bios, or something...

I bought a $500 docking station that can run 3 monitors, but they all working in `usb type c alt mode`, meaning that they depending on the original video card capacity. Since `Intel Pro Graphics 630` can only handle 3 screens - the first is built into a laptop, the second is connected to the laptop directly. So I only left with one screen that can be connected via a new docking station. So now I have 2 display ports on my new docking station that cannot be utilized. I feel upset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking a [random processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/201894/intel-core-i310105-processor-6m-cache-up-to-4-40-ghz.html) with Intel Pro Graphics 630 you can scroll down the the graphics section where you will see

> # (Number) of Displays Supported: 3

This is obviously dependent on how many connections are wired up on your specific machine, some laptops may only have a single connector for external displays and so the total displays would be two, with one being your built in display.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed.  As you said "how many connections are wired" - that is exactly my point. I bought a $500 docking station that can run 3 monitors, but they all working in `usb type c alt mode`, meaning that they depending on the original video card capacity. Since `Intel Pro Graphics 630` can only handle 3 screens - the first is built into a laptop, the second is connected to the laptop directly. So I only left with one screen that can be connected via a new docking station. So now I have 2 display ports on my new docking station that cannot be utilized. I feel upset.

Comment: It's possible to get USB to video dongles that provide some kind of software based output that I think isn't reliant on the internal video hardware itself. This might be an alternative for additional monitors.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev sadly Alt-mode doesn't remove all limitations, but as pointed out by Zhro there are devices such as https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/d/B0B1TPF1QV that allow you to connect additional displays over USB. Some of these mention "DisplayLink" or that they are a "USB graphics card", so basically what you need is a device that does not rely on your processor. I remember the USB 2 versions of these being kinda slow but newer USB 3 versions might actually be okay.